# appending another object model to a model Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, eloquent

```
comment:Array(2)
    0:{id: 1, user_id: 10, answer_id: 6, comment_content: "This is first comment ever in this", parent_id: 0, …}
    1:{id: 6, user_id: 10, answer_id: 6, comment_content: "This is commenting again let's see whether it works or not, It should work.", parent_id: 0, …}
```

I am getting an array of objects...
Let's say i have three eloquent model Comment and User, Answer. I am just showing two comments which belongs to an answer. I want to also show user associated to each comments as you can see there is a user_id which is a foreign key

I want to get something like this using eloquent only ... how do i use append method

```
comment:Array(2)
    0:{id: 1, user_id: 10, name: "Jonh Doe" email: 'john@xyz.com', answer_id: 6, comment_content: "This is first comment ever in this", parent_id: 0, …}
    1:{id: 6, user_id: 10, name: "Foo", email:'foo@xyz.com', answer_id: 6, comment_content: "This is commenting again let's see whether it works or not, It should work.", parent_id: 0, …}
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

Comment: Can you show us the controller code?

Comment: it's done, just followed link(docs) Thanks